# Rigid Automorphisms of n-dimensional cube

Tags: group-theory, automorphism-group

I know how to compute the automorphism group of an n-dimensional cube, but I do not know which subgroup of this group is the rigid automorphisms of the n-dimensional hypercube(The subgroups which consist of all automorphisms of n-cube which can be realized in n-dimensional euclidean space with only rigid motions.)

Comment: If you post your knowledge about the group of automorphisms of the $n$-dimensional cube, then it will be easier to point out to you what that subgroup is.

Comment: I know that it is the hyperoctahedral group. I have read its Wikipedia page.

Comment: All right, now check whether the generators of the hyperoctahedral group can be realised by rigid motions.